# Create SAS table header flexibly

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I want to create a table head for a table, replacing the orignal table head.

The table head contains two rows:

head1 = !!!SS!FAS!PPS!

head2 = !Index!!(N=30)!(N=30)!(N=30)!

Here the ! meaning column delimiter. The head1 is the first row of table head .In head1, the first and second column are blank and the content of third, fourth and fifith are SS, FAS and PPS.

The head2 is the second row of table head, the content of the first column is index; the second is blank; the third to fifth are (N-30).

I want to form the following table head:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bPoE.png)

Comment: Which PROC is being used for output ?  Can you show sample data ? Do you need to compute the N statistic before outputting the table ?

Comment: Please show anything you've tried to solve this issue. This is a topic that's been documented quite well so there's a lot of examples out there, search for 'clinical reports sas' on lexjansen.com or using your preferred search engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ods inline styling to place a newline in a columns label (which is used for the header in output).  Inline styling is introduced using a special *escapechar* of your choosing. Also, during output, a blank label is replaced with the column name, so use a hard-space character (A0) to force a blank header.

```
data have;
  index = 1;
  blank = ' ';
  ss = 1;
  fas = 2;
  pps = 3;
run;

ods escapechar='^';

proc print noobs data=have label;
  var index blank ss fas pps blank;
  label 
    index = '^nIndex'
    blank = '0A'x
    ss = 'SS^n(N=30)'
    fas = 'FAS^n(N=30)'
    pps = 'PPS^n(N=30)'
  ;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Richard, Thanks for your idea. I want to write a macro mreport. This macro accepts the head parameter like above example. This macro just generates the table head. The table data has been calculated before. Your plan is a little concrete. I need to transform the head(!!!SS!FAS!PPS!) into your form first. If there is rtf grammer to recognize such form(!!!SS!FAS!PPS!)directly?

Comment: Typically, SAS tabled output with header and data rows is done all with in a single PROC step.  You could programmatically generate label statements from a !!! valued construct in prior code. If the construct does not involve discernable columns you would want to specify them as well.  Try coding some and make a new question with sample data and code if you run into problems.